# Python print incomplete data

Tags: python, file

I have the following data in raw_data.txt

```
id=001;name=Johan Strauss;address=58 Jalan Jelutong, 11600 Pulau Pinang, Malaysia;gender=male
id=002;name=Jennifer Teng;address=Q-2-4,Desa Indah, Lorong Minyak, 13000 Kedah, Malaysia;gender=female
```

I ran the following code:

```
f = open('raw_data.txt', 'r')
for x in f:
x = x.replace("id","Student",)
x = x.replace("name","Name")
x = x.replace("address","Home Number")
x = x.replace("gender","Gender")
x = x.replace(";","\n")
print (x)

g = open('formatted.txt','a')
g.write(x)
```

This is the output I got in formatted.txt

```
Student=002
Name=Jennifer Teng
Home Number=Q-2-4,Desa Indah, Lorong Minyak, 13000 Kedah, Malaysia
Gender=female
```

I lost student 001 data. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi Zaim, I believe it could be because `g` is not inside of your loop, you need to add it inside of it. It is difficult to tell because identation is important in python and your code is not well formatted. Can you give the correct format to your code? This will allow other contributors to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to close the file that you opened.
Your code has an indentation problem that the for loop iterates line by line. The corrected code can be corrected as follows:

```
f = open('raw_data.txt', 'r')
y=''
for x in f:
    x = x.replace("id","Student")
    x = x.replace("name","Name")
    x = x.replace("address","Home Number")
    x = x.replace("gender","Gender")
    x = x.replace(";","\n")
    y=y+x #Used to store the newly formated text of each line
print(y)
f.close()
g = open('formatted.txt','a')
g.write(y) #Write the updated information to the file
g.close()
```

Comment: Hi, how can I delete a line that does not contain "=" in it?

Comment: You can search the line that has the "=" sign and filter them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: you are writing to file in the end only once but processing more student data in the for loop before. The x variable only stores the final value and writes the student 002 data only.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: # reading all data line by line from the raw_data.txt
    data = f.readlines()
    
with open('formatted.txt', 'w') as f: # writing data to new file student by student
    for student in data:
        student = student.strip().replace("id","Student").replace("name","Name").replace("address","Home Number").replace("gender","Gender").replace(";","\n")
        f.write(student)
        print(student)
```

[File output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPCQ3.png)